# Bash Script - Using Basename to Output to File

Tags: bash, unix

I've created a small script to test out getting the basename of all files in the current directory. I want to output them all to a file `output.txt` but using a for loop, of course the file is just overwritten each time. Using the following code, how could I modify it to simply append each one to the end of the file (simply)?

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find -size +100)

for f in $files; do
    basename "$f" > output.txt
done

exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or the oneliner:

```
find -size +100 -exec basename "{}" \; >> output
```

Comment: can you store this to a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Use MrAfs' suggestion and move the redirection to the end of the loop. By using `>` instead of `>>` you don't have to truncate the file explicitly.

Also, use a `while read` loop so it works in case there are spaces in filenames. The `exit` at the end is redundant.

```
#!/bin/bash

find -size +100 | while read -r f
do
    basename "$f"
done > output.txt
```

In some cases, you will want to avoid creating a subshell. You can use process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r f
do
    basename "$f"
done < <(find -size +100) > output.txt
```

or in the upcoming Bash 4.2:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s lastpipe    
find -size +100 | while read -r f
do
    basename "$f"
done > output.txt
```

Comment: Can I store to a variable instead of an output file?

Comment: @rar: Yes, but you should probably pipe it into another loop instead or do your additional processing in the loop shown. Why do you want it in a variable? If you seem to need to, there's a good chance your program needs to be restructured. You may want to use an array or a function, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `>>` to append to the file instead of `>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect bash constructs

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find -size +100)

for f in $files; do
    basename "$f" 
done > output.txt

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
rm -f output.txt
for f in $files; do
    basename "$f" >> output.txt
done
```

Or this:

```
for f in $files; do
    basename "$f"
done > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Without calling basename:

```
find -size +100 -printf "%f\n" > output.txt
```

Comment: can you store this to a variable?

Comment: sure, like this: `files=$(find -size +100 -printf "%f\n")`